# SystemUnathorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, discord

I am working on building a Discord bot for a class using C#, but for whatever reason when I try to run my group's code after cloning it, I keep getting:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Access to the path
>   '/Users/ajgoddu/Desktop/Projects/CS3141/Scrum-Bot/ScrumBot/ScrumBot/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1'
>   is denied.

The lines causing the exception:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
=> new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I'm using a Macbook Pro, on OSX Mojave 10.14.1.
I am running the latest version of VS Code, as well as .NET and mono, and have made sure that the folders in questions are not read-only. I have even tried running VS code with `sudo`, to no avail.

Anyone able to help? I've tried many different fixes as well as reinstalled .NET, mono, and VS multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to identify which process is blocking that DLL to be used and throwing unauthorized exception; you can kill that process and then running; or may be you'll get to know the problem.

Comment: I put it in the title but forgot to re-iterate in the body that I am running OS X, I tried using process explorer with wine but for whatever reason it is unable to run it. I took a look with activity monitor but was unable to identify what might be using the dll.